# Did starred message ordering change?

Tags: support, bug, chat, chat-stars

I looked at the starred message list in the Python chat room today, and it looks like the algorithm that decides what to show there has changed. There are a lot more high-starred old messages and a lot less low-starred new messages.

Looking at the [full list](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/6/python/?tab=stars) of starred messages in the room, I thought maybe messages had become unstarred somehow, but it turns out the full list isn't in chronological order; it seems to be in the same order as the short list displayed in the actual chat room, just with more messages.

Did something change the order recently?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. :/

Comment: Hmmm, will add to the bug list here. Did the algorithm change? No - no code changes, but the SQL Database compat level did change for chat recently (130 was unfriendly so it had remained at 110 until being bumped to 140 recently which had much better CE behavior for some chat use cases). My off-the-top-of-my-head guess would be there's a non-deterministic query for this that *just happened to work* before but needs actual ordering applied. It's only a guess though. Will need to dig in and look.